# JavaScript RegEx to white list chars, how bad is my approach?

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm using JavaScript RegEx to filter input (white list only acceptable chars).  As .match() returns an array, the best way I found to 'glue' back together the string is as follows, which seems ugly, as then I have to remove the comma.

```
myString.match(/[A-Za-z-_0-9]/g).toString().replace(/,/g,'')
```

Is there a better RegEx approach in JS, or a better way to handle the array (e.g. like .join in Ruby)?

Thanks
Brian

Answer (score 10):

There is a [`join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join) in JavaScript as well. For instance:

```
myString.match(/[A-Za-z-_0-9]/g).join("")
```

The `""` is the separator between each element of the array, so `[1, 2, 3].join("")` gives `"123"`. However, you could also simply replace all characters not in your whitelist:

```
myString.replace(/[^A-Za-z-_0-9]/g, "")
```

Which will simply remove any character that isn't alphanumeric, a dash, or an underscore.

Comment: Thanks.  I just found the .join method (should have looked deeper first).  Your RexEx works great, I forgot about the ^.